# Why is my new Apple TV suddenly not showing my purchased TV shows?

Tags: appletv, itunes-store

A few days ago, my new Apple TV stopped showing me my purchased TV shows.

When I select the TV Shows app on the home screen, and click on the “Purchased” tab, I get a spinner that never goes away.

When I do the same for the Movies app, I see all my purchased movies. I can also see my purchased TV shows in iTunes on my Mac.

I also just get an eternal spinner if I try to purchase a TV show. Interestingly though, if I search for a TV episode that I know I’ve purchased (e.g. “show me Star Trek The Next Generation season four episode one”) and click on it, it will play. And I can purchase shows from iTunes on my Mac, and immediately play them on the Apple TV using the above method.

I’ve tried restarting the Apple TV; signing out of my iTunes and App Store account, and my iCloud account, and back in again; and re-setting the Apple TV, all to no effect.

Anyone else getting this?

Comment: no issues here. We have three devices and use two accounts on them. The things you tried look good. Next stop, Apple customer support....

Comment: I have an Apple TV, and have no issues. Best bet is call apple support. Could be a server-side issue

Comment: @user2277872 Apple have a live chat support option! Which, after one disconnection and a fairly slow response time, told me to ring them instead  ask ask for their “multimedia” team. I thus entirely agree that calling them is the best option.

Comment: I just noticed this today (three days or more after your post).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Last night, I did a [support webchat with Apple UK](https://www.apple.com/uk/support/appletv/contact/) about the issue, telling them the above.

They confirmed that those were the steps that they would have advised. They told me to phone their support line (0800 107 6285, 08:00–19:45 Monday–Sunday in the UK), and ask for “multimedia” support.

However, this morning, my purchased TV shows were suddenly showing up again, I guess about five days after they disappeared.

Answer (score 2):

I was having this same issue. I have Restrictions turned on so my kids couldn't buy anything. It's supposed to ask for a passcode (which it does when buying apps). Trying to buy something on iTunes just caused the spinner to spin forever. I turned off Restictions and it worked the first time!

Comment: Good to know. I don’t have restrictions turned on.

Answer (score 1):

You are not alone.  I have seen the same thing.  No purchases for tv shows but I can see my favs and can access my stuff from search.  Which probably means one or more of the servers that own our data is bad in some way or another.

Going to try logging out/in again as that has worked in the past.

Good luck.